# Angular 2 - autofill issue with ng-reflect-model

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular2-forms

input i have is getting filled with a mail-id automatically
i have tried using autocomplete="none|false|no but no change,

Code :

```
 <input  [(ngModel)]="query"  type="text" 
 class="form-control search-control" 
 placeholder="Search for orders (by order number)"
 autocomplete="off">
```

this is the input i have given

```
<input _ngcontent-c1="" autocomplete="off"
 class="form-control search-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"
 placeholder="Search for orders (by order number)" 
type="search" ng-reflect-model="shopadmin@zaska.com">
```

this is what i get when i inspect

[image]

attached image of autofill

How to overcome this autofill issue!

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.
So with below solution, I have resolved it.

> Step 1) Add `autocomplete="off"` on form level
>   Step 2) Add `autocomplete="fake-email"` on that input type

Note: 'fake-email' is just a text, you can write anything instead of that.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="fake-email">
</form>
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: thanks for your time, it actually works but when i add this , the functionality given to the input is not working(search is not working).